# How to assign the HTML onmouseover event handler within image area map?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I set a onmouseover event handler through using an image map. I wish there to be an image, and as a user hovers over a certain part of the image (set via map co-ordinates) another image should be displayed on top of the initial image within the context of the specified co-ordinates. This is what I have so far but it's not working:

```
<center>
<p><img src="main.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://google.com" shape="poly" coords="190,187,163,186,161,139,188,141" onmouseover="this.src='change-face-one.jpg';" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://example.com" shape="poly" coords="203,120,202,158,232,159,232,124" onmouseover="this.src='change-face-two.jpg';" />
</map>
</center>
```

Comment: I'd use absolutely positioned `<a>`s inside a wrapper `<div>` and CSS sprites to change (shift) the `background-image` (i.e. use `:hover` and `background-position`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<map>` is a DOM element. Therefore `this` in javascript is referencing the #map and NOT the image.

Try giving the image an ID and referencing that.

```
<center>
<p><img src="main.jpg" alt="" id="theImage" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://google.com" shape="poly" coords="190,187,163,186,161,139,188,141" onmouseover="document.getElementByID('theImage').src='change-face-one.jpg';" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="http://example.com" shape="poly" coords="203,120,202,158,232,159,232,124" onmouseover="document.getElementByID('theImage').src='change-face-two.jpg';" />
</map>
</center>
```

Also, without seeing your images, it's difficult to know what, if any issues they may be causing. For example, if they're different sizes they could cause your hot spots to stop working.

Comment: Hey Bryce, thank you for taking your time to respond to this. I have put the images up on imgur and re-worked the code. However, it still isn't working, see here: https://pastebin.com/raw/6Ej5bUYY - what am I doing wrong? Also when you run the HTML, the area of interest pertaining to the onmouseover event handler is located on one of the top-left faces (look for change in mouse icon).

Comment: Now that I see what you're doing, I'm not sure you want to swap the src. Would it be better to hide or show an image stacked on top of the other image?

Comment: Yeah I think that would be better actually. How would I go about doing this? Appreciate your time, I'm not very familiar with these area maps.

Comment: Well basically I would keep the image map you have and stack another image on top of it. Probably start with it transparent. Then use javascript to change the top image on rollover. I think some of the issues you were seeing had to do with swapping the mapped img src to a different size image that was missing the map coordinates.

Comment: I'll try to add an example later today

Comment: @Jase did you solve this? I got sidetracked and didn't add an example. If you're still working on this, I'd be happy to add something!

Comment: Hey Bryce, yes I did :) Thank you anyway for your assistance :)